# Multiple checkboxes type for Jeditable

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jeditable

I'm using the excellent jEditable plugin for some in-place editing on my page. There is one spot I need a multiple checkboxes element. Is there a jEditable plugin that allows me to do this?

I would need a new type to meet one of my needs : a multi-checkboxes type that could be called "checkboxes".

When editing the field typed "checkboxes", a checkbox list appears and would allow users to select multiple choices. Saving would return an array and update.php will store this array in my DB.

eg:

```
<div style="border:red 1px solid;" class="editable"> this is test !</div>
```

after click the div, the content of div should be like: [image]

I DO NOT WANT MULTI-SELECT LIKE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lANX1.png

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Following code might help........

For this we need two javascript,
1) jquery-1.9.1.js or any
2) jquery.jeditable.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello!!!</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $.editable.addInputType('checkbox', {
        element: function(settings, original) {
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check1_" name="check" value="OTCS" /> OTCS');
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check2_" name="check" value="OCJ" /> OCJ');
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check3_" name="check" value="OCAD" /> OCAD');
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check4_" name="check" value="OCB" /> OCB');
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check5_" name="check" value="ZINZENDORF" /> ZINZENDORF');
            $(this).append('<input type="checkbox" id="check6_" name="check" value="Others" /> Others');
            var hidden = $('<input type="hidden"/>');
            $(this).append(hidden);
            return(hidden);
        },
        submit: function (settings, original) {
            //some code
        },
        content: function(string, settings, original) {
            //some code
         }
     });

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#cb').editable('www.some.com/some.php',{
             indicator: '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
         tooltip: 'Click to select',
         loadtext: 'loading...',
         type:   'checkbox',
             onblur: 'submit',
             cancel: 'Cancel',
             submit: 'OK'
         });
     });
     </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <div style="border:red 1px solid;" id="cb"> Click me to turn in CheckBox....... </div>
</body>
```

[image: First]

[image: After]